# Como puedo eliminar signos de puntuación que no me interesan en una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista

Tengo una lista de strings en Python que contiene palabras con signos de puntuación. El problema es que hay algunas palabras que, por los signos de puntuación, las agrupan como si fueran una sola de la siguiente forma:

```py
['e-learning', 'web 2.0', 'economía; ley; química', 'mañana / día', 'distancia - etiqueta - km']
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer es separar esas palabras que contienen más de una en palabras independientes cada una de ellas. ¿Como podría hacerlo?

El resultado que debería quedar es el siguiente:

```py
['e-learning', 'web 2.0', 'economía', 'ley', 'química', 'mañana', 'día,' noche ', 'distancia', 'etiqueta', 'km']
```

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y lee [ask]. Para que tu pregunta sea válida debes mostrar lo que has intentado, tratando de ofrecer un [mcve]. En la forma en que se encuentra posiblemente sea cerrada.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar expresiones regulares para hacer la separación. Para tu ejemplo algo así puede valer:

```py
import re

regex = '; | - | / '

entrada = ['e-learning', 'web 2.0', 'economía; ley; química', 'mañana / día', 'distancia - etiqueta - km']
salida = []

for palabra in entrada:
  salida.extend(re.split(regex, palabra))

print(salida)
```

El resultado de salida:

```py
['e-learning', 'web 2.0', 'economía', 'ley', 'química', 'mañana', 'día', 'distancia', 'etiqueta', 'km']
```

Comment: Revisa tu respuesta. Prueba con ["palabra;"]

Comment: Eso ya depende de los casos especificos que necesite como separador, sería añadir casos a la expresión regular

Answer (score 1):

Un signo de puntuación es un caracter seguido de un espacio en blanco. Un signo al final de una cadena se supone implícitamente seguido de un espacio en blanco.

El algoritmo es: examinar cada parte (elemento) en la lista `texto`. Por cada parte, revisar si contiene algún signo indeseado. En tal caso, dividir la parte por el signo indeseado y luego procesar cada parte recursivamente y retornar una lista con los resultados.

```
def limpiar(texto, indeseados):
    """
    Elimina signos de puntuacion en un texto.
    
    :param texto: Una lista de textos. 
    :param indeseados: Una cadena o lista de signos de puntuación.
    :return: El texto sin los signos.
    """
    salida=[]
    for parte in texto:
        largo_salida = len(salida)
        for ind in indeseados:
            if ind == parte[-1]:
                # Caso especial: el indeseado es el último caracter,
                # simplemente lo eliminamos de la palabra.
                # Casos como indeseados = ":" y palabra = "fin:"
                parte = parte[:-1]

            buscar = ind + " "
            if buscar in parte:
                subpartes = [x.strip() for x in parte.split(buscar)]
                salida.extend(limpiar(subpartes, indeseados))
                #   Solo se realiza una eliminación de indeseados en 'parte'
                #   Si hay más indeseados, se eliminan recursivamente.
                break

        if largo_salida == len(salida):
            # La 'parte' no contiene ningun signo de puntuación.
            salida.append(parte)

    return salida
```

**Comprobación**

```
signos = ",.:;/-"
tests = [["Opciones: dia / noche - invierno / verano", "uno, dos, tres", " marzo - abril - may"],
         ["lista:", "entonces;", "fin."],
         ["Horario: 8:00 - 20:00", "Valores: $1,20,   $2,40,    $3,50"],
         ["siguiente", "23/5/2020", "clase::metodo", "e-learning", "web 2.0"]
         ]

print(f"Signos a eliminar: {signos}")
print("")
for test in tests:
    print(f"Lista original: {test}")
    print(f"Lista limpiada: {limpiar(test, signos)}")
    print("")
```

produce:

```
Signos a eliminar: ,.:;/-

Lista original: ['Opciones: dia / noche - invierno / verano', 'uno, dos, tres', ' marzo - abril - may']
Lista limpiada: ['Opciones', 'dia', 'noche', 'invierno', 'verano', 'uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'marzo', 'abril', 'may']

Lista original: ['lista:', 'entonces;', 'fin.']
Lista limpiada: ['lista', 'entonces', 'fin']

Lista original: ['Horario: 8:00 - 20:00', 'Valores: $1,20,   $2,40,    $3,50']
Lista limpiada: ['Horario', '8:00', '20:00', 'Valores', '$1,20', '$2,40', '$3,50']

Lista original: ['siguiente', '23/5/2020', 'clase::metodo', 'e-learning', 'web 2.0']
Lista limpiada: ['siguiente', '23/5/2020', 'clase::metodo', 'e-learning', 'web 2.0']
```

Comment: He probado lo que me has comentado, pero me sale el siguiente error:  RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceed while calling a Python object. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: @drakitus98. ¿Con que datos?

Comment: Una lista de strings que contiene 10.000 palabras.

Comment: @drakitus98. Procesa por partes.